# Which scope should it use if I put ng-controller and one directive on same tag in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

All:

Like title says, I put ng-controller and a directive on `<body>` tag like:

```
<body ng-controller="main" global-control>
```

And controller and directive like:

```
        .controller("main", function($scope){
            $scope.name = "hello";
         })
        .directive("globalControl", function($timeout){
            return {
                restrict: "A",
                scope:false,
                link: function(scope, EL, attrs){
                    EL.on("click", function(){
                        scope.name = "hola"
                    });
                }
            }
         })
```

I already specify no new scope create in directive, but why when I click the body, the name can not changed to "hola"? And only way to change it is call scope.$apply wrapping it?

Comment: What is the purpose of using ng-controller and not just specifying the controller on your directive?

Comment: @AmyBlankenship Just for curious purpose.. I structure the scope into UI logic and data logic, so most UI logic in Directive and Data logic in that main controller

Answer (score 0):

For event handlers bound by JQLite (or JQuery), the AngularJS framework needs to be notified of changes to scope. Use `scope.$apply` for that:

```
    .controller("main", function($scope){
        $scope.name = "hello";
     })
    .directive("globalControl", function($timeout){
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            scope:false,
            link: function(scope, EL, attrs){
                EL.on("click", function(){
                    //scope.name = "hola"
                    scope.$apply("name='hola'");
                });
            }
        }
     })
```

For more information, see [AngularJS $rootScope.scope API Reference -- $apply](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply)